# Template pointer without knowing the type

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, generics

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
    private:
    T data;
    public:
    Container(T newData) : data(newData) {}
    T getData() {return data;}
};


int main()
{
    Container* numContainer=new Container<int>(5);
    //Do something with numContainer
    delete numContainer;
}
```

This doesn't compile since the type of the `Container` pointer must be specified, such as `int`.
This can, as I found out after some quick googling, be dealt with by creating a `ContainerBase` class which is not a template and let `Container` derive from it. Letting the pointer be of type `ContainerBase` will however not let me use methods such as `getData()` since it returns type `T` and can therefore not be declared in the `ContainerBase` class.

Can I somehow have a pointer which can point to an instance of a template class of any type, even if the class contains methods such as in the example above?

Comment: Not without resorting to some sort of type erasure. `Container<int>` and `Container<double>` are actually two different, unrelated classes and the fact that they contain members with the same names is just a coincidence as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: How do you intend to use `getData` without knowing the type `T` somehow?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to accomplish a tagged union may be what you need.

Comment: @Yakk To be honest, I don't know. This was a problem I encountered a while ago, but I did some things differently and was no longer in need a feature like this. I guess what you say is true, there's no real way I could use those problematic methods anyway.

Comment: Something you might have most probably tried - but unable to use. Anyway. If you are using c++ 11 why not use auto?

Comment: I don’t understand why not write `Container<int>* numContainer=new Container<int>(5);`

Comment: I don’t understand what you are actually trying to achieve. You should note however that templates are compile-time polymorphism, while inheritance achieves run-time polymorphism

Comment: When creating an instance of a template class you have to specify what it is. Without specifying your pointer it can't point anyway to Container<int>. It's like you want to make 'int' point to 'double' but even worse since 'int' in your case ('Container') is not even specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Can I somehow have a pointer which can point to an instance of a template class of any type, even if the class contains methods such as in the example above?*

No you can't, for your `template class` to be instantiated the compiler must know the type of `T`. Think of a class template as a blueprint of a class and not as a concrete definition of a class. For every type you specify for your template class (e.g., `Container<int>`) the compiler generates a separate definition. The compiler when it sees the name of your template class (e.g., `Container`) can't deduce its type out of thin air.

IMHO, The best you can do in order to avoid explicitly specifying every time the type of the template is to use aliases like the example below:

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
  T data;
public:
  Container(T const &newData) : data(newData) {}
  T getData() const {return data;}
};

using iContainer = Container<int>;

int main() {
    iContainer* numContainer=new iContainer(5);
    //Do something with numContainer
    delete numContainer;
}
```

Or use runtime polymorphism as you've already mentioned in combination with use of `dynamic_cast` like the example below:

```
class BaseContainer {
public:
    virtual ~BaseContainer() {}
};

template <typename T>
class Container : public BaseContainer {
  T data;
public:
  Container(T const &newData) : data(newData) {}
  T getData() const {return data;}
};

int main() {
  BaseContainer *numContainer = new Container<int>(5);

  Container<int> *ptr = dynamic_cast<Container<int>*>(numContainer);
  if(ptr) std::cout << ptr->getData() << std::endl;;
  delete numContainer;
}
```

### **[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da8ad9bb9a8aa031)**